# Change Nginx ingress controller Static IP to reserved static ip after deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, static-ip-address

I have two ingress controller deployed in two different namespaces in Azure K8s cluster

```
ingress-A           ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.131.22    20.xx.xx.xx    80:31788/TCP,443:30605/TCP   89s
ingress-A           ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.171.187   <none>           443/TCP                      89s
ingress-B           ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.61.156    52.xx.xx.xx    80:31966/TCP,443:30125/TCP   18m
ingress-B           ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.97.78     <none>           443/TCP                      18m
```

I have already two static IP that are assigned to my domain which i would like to use instead of the one Azure K8s cluster generated.

I try to figure how I can update these IP to mine But i couldnt a find a way.

I have tried this:

```
kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx-iot -p '{"status": {"loadBalancer": {"ingress":{"ip":"my new ip address"}}}}'
```

i got this error:

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[status:map[loadBalancer:map[ingress:map[ip:20.76.109.236]]]]": cannot restore slice from map
```

I tried to modify them from Azure K8s cluster portal but didn't work as well.

Comment: For the first option the documentation link has different topic then mine :), for the second option I added a spec loadbalcerIp field in the service using this command `kubectl patch svc ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx-iot -p '{"selector": {"loadBalancerIP": "newip"}}` but didnt work the static Ip didnt change

Comment: @ikenhaim Deleted my last comment, apologies, pasted you the wrong link. Correct comment: 1. Have you tried to delete the `Service` and create it once more in accordance to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip)? 2. I'd reckon you are trying to change to value in the `status`. Have you tried to change/add the `spec.loadBalancerIP` field in the `Service` definition?